# Base url with multi page apps using vite

Tags: rollupjs, vite

For my multi page app i cannot have html assets imports pointing to the root as i need to upload my project inside a sub-folder.

Using -

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  base: "./",
});
```

resolves this issue for root pages but cause a wrong import for nested pages.

Example

```
 - assets
 - index.html
 - nested
   - nested.html
```

Imports for index.html will point to ./assets which is correct.

Imports for nested.html will also point to ./assets which is incorrect. It needs to point to ../assets instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an `alias` to point to the `assets` folder :

```js
alias: {
    "@": resolve(__dirname, './assets'),
 },
```

Based on your tree sample, with this following example of multipage `vite.config.js`, you can import assets
from components with: `import logo from '@/logo.png'` *(assuming there is a `logo.png` file in folder `assets`)*

```js
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { join, parse, resolve } from "path";

export default {
  base: '',
  root: './',
  plugins: [vue()],
  alias: {
    "@": resolve(__dirname, './assets'), // will resolve to `/assets/`
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: entryPoints(
        "index.html",
        "nested/nested.html",
        "foo/index.html",
        "foo/bar/index.html",
      ),
    },
  },
};

function entryPoints(...paths) {
  const entries = paths.map(parse).map(entry => {
    const { dir, base, name, ext } = entry;
    const key = join(dir, name);
    const path = resolve(__dirname, dir, base);
    return [key, path];
  });
  
  const config = Object.fromEntries(entries);
  return config;
}
```

Example code of the nested `FooBar` component :

```js
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" :src="logo" />
  <Nav/>
  <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
  import Nav from "~/components/Nav.vue";
  import logo from '@/logo.png'

  import "@/style/style.scss"
</script>
```